Clang 18.1.5 and the support of std::println
I have recently upgraded my Clang compiler on my M1 Mini Mac from Clang 17.0.6 to Clang 18.1.5 through brew package manager. I had few test programmes that had the std::println which worked fine with the Clang 17.0.6. Now with Clang 18.1.5 I get the below error message:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__1::__is_posix_terminal(__sFILE*)", referenced from:
      std::__1::__print::__is_terminal[abi:ne180100](__sFILE*) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I am not sure if the support of std::println or the <print> header library was removed from Clang 18.1.6? I have tried to search the release notes but did not find anything related to this topic. I am by the way specifying the C++ standard as 23 in my CMakeLists.txt

It was a linker issue to the proper libc++. I am not sure what happened with the brew update that it changed installation locations without having the symbolic links. I have reinstalled llvm via brew and got the below messages:
To use the bundled libc++ please add the following LDFLAGS:
  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++"
llvm is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
If you need to have llvm first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find llvm you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/include"

So, I have added the below line to my CMakeLists.txt, and everything then worked as it is supposed to with std::println
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -L/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/c++")


I am using macports and had the same issue. Got it resolved in a similar fashion (suggested by JBQ) but for the macports scenario. Funny thing it was working just a day before without having to resort to this solution.
The issue
$ clang++ -std=c++23 -Wall -rpath /opt/local/libexec/llvm-18/lib crtp-using-concept.cpp
ld: Undefined symbols:
  std::__1::__is_posix_terminal(__sFILE*), referenced from:
      std::__1::__print::__is_terminal[abi:ne180100](__sFILE*) in crtp-using-concept-7177ea.o
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Finding the cause
Reverted to cout just to get the program to link and find the dependencies.
$ clang++ -std=c++23 -Wall crtp-using-concept.cpp

$ otool -L a.out
a.out:
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1600.157.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.61.1)

For whatever reason clang++ doesn't want to link with the libraries that ship with the corresponding versions. With that clue, reverted back to using println in code and started twiddling with rpath and -L options.
First, rpath is not about finding the library at link time but at runtime. So adding rpath doesn't help get past the linker error (in clang18). In clang18, it's required to use both -L and -rpath to get the issue resolved.
# no dice with just -rpath
$ clang++ -std=c++23 -Wall -rpath /opt/local/libexec/llvm-18/lib crtp-using-concept.cpp
ld: Undefined symbols:
  std::__1::__is_posix_terminal(__sFILE*), referenced from:
      std::__1::__print::__is_terminal[abi:ne180100](__sFILE*) in crtp-using-concept-e29092.o
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

# Compiles and links with -L alone but bails at runtime
$ clang++ -std=c++23 -Wall -L/opt/local/libexec/llvm-18/lib/ crtp-using-concept.cpp

$ otool -L a.out
a.out:
        @rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.61.1)
        @rpath/libunwind.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

$ ./a.out 
dyld[76535]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <205D6B8E-EA28-3303-A1AA-087F5082B920> a.out
  Reason: no LC_RPATH's found
Abort trap: 6

The solution
Find where the version of libc++ that comes with the version of clang in use and explicitly specify the locations.
# use both -L and -rpath (dumb of clang, if you ask me; maybe it is a macports issue)
$ clang++ -std=c++23 -Wall -L/opt/local/libexec/llvm-18/lib/ -rpath /opt/local/libexec/llvm-18/lib crtp-using-concept.cpp

# how the executable should look when linked correctly
$ otool -L a.out
a.out:
        @rpath/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.61.1)
        @rpath/libunwind.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

# Follow the dependency chain to see that we are looking at the right location
$ otool -l a.out
...
...
Load command 13
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name @rpath/libc++.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Wed Dec 31 16:00:02 1969
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
...
Load command 16
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 48
         path /opt/local/libexec/llvm-18/lib (offset 12)
...

# and when linked correctly, it should work without runtime failures
$ ./a.out 
Hello, world!

